# Stacked time series plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, programming

I have multiple time series measured in different units. I want to have a stacked plot of my data with a common x-axis. An example would be [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stackedplot.html). For illustration, here is my data.

```
nobs = 100;
TS1= RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], nobs];
TS2= Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 5], nobs]];
TS3= RandomInteger[{-10, 100}, nobs];
dates = DateRange[DatePlus[Today, Quantity[-nobs + 1, "Days"]], Today];
mytsdata = TimeSeries[#, {dates}] & /@ {TS1, TS2, TS3};
mergeddata = TimeSeriesThread[# &, mytsdata];
```

I can use `DateListPlot` or `StackedDateListPlot` to plot my data set `mytsdata` or `mergeddata` but none of these plots serve my interest. I created a graph using MATLAB and looks like this.
[image]

Is it possible to create a similar graph using Ma codes? Flexibility to change graph properties would add much value. The main requirement is that there has to be one and only one x-axis. **Time series could be of different lengths.**

**Update:** Here is a list of several time series with different lengths.

```
nobs = 100;
dates = DateRange[DatePlus[Today, Quantity[-nobs + 1, "Days"]], Today];
s1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], nobs];
s1ts = TimeSeries[s1, {dates}];
s2 = Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 5], nobs - 25]];
s2ts = TimeSeries[s2, {dates[[26 ;;]]}];
s3 = RandomInteger[{-10, 100}, nobs - 50];
s3ts = TimeSeries[s3, {dates[[51 ;;]]}];
mergeddata2 = 
  TimeSeriesThread[# &, {s1ts, s2ts, s3ts}, 
   ResamplingMethod -> Missing[]];
```

I want to plot `mergeddata2` as follows.
[image]
Time and 2020 at the bottom of the graph are not required. Thank you in advance.

**Update 2:**

Incorporating Rohit's suggestion, I was able to generate my graph with the following codes:

```
drange = {mergeddata2["Dates"][[1]], mergeddata2["Dates"][[-1]]};
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {DateListPlot[s1ts, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]},
  {DateListPlot[s2ts, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]},
  {DateListPlot[s3ts, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]}
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Any suggestions for further improvement would be welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resource function [PlotGrid](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) has a lot of options for controlling the layout and axes.

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][mytsdata // Map[DateListPlot /* List]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Rohit,  thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DLT You are welcome, but you should really thank Lucas Lang, the author of `PlotGrid` :-).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi -- You definitely win the code golf match.  What an elegant solution.  I hadn't known these `ResourceFunction`s existed.  Many thanks.

Comment: @ Rohit, with your suggestion, I was able to generate the graph:     drange = {mergeddata2["Dates"][[1]], mergeddata2["Dates"][[-1]]};
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {DateListPlot[s1ts, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]},
  {DateListPlot[s2ts, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]},
  {DateListPlot[s3ts, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {drange, Automatic}]}
  }
 ]

Comment: @DLT Cool. Another way to generate `drange` without the need for `TimeSeriesThread`. `{s1ts, s2ts, s3ts} // Map[{#["FirstDate"], #["LastDate"]} &] // MinMax`.

Answer (score 5):

This gets you most of what you want.

That said, I've edited this post a couple of times to arrive at the current solution.

```
Grid[{
{"TS1",DateListPlot[mytsdata[[1]], ImageSize -> 350, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImagePadding -> {{25, 1}, {0, 0}}]},
{"TS2", DateListPlot[mytsdata[[2]], ImageSize -> 350, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImagePadding -> {{25, 1}, {0, 0}}]},
{"TS3", DateListPlot[mytsdata[[3]], ImageSize -> 350, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImagePadding -> {{25, 1}, {15, 0}}]},
{"", "TIME               2020"}
},
Alignment -> {Right, Left}]
```

[image]

Some explanation follows...

Mathematica, at least to my knowledge, doesn't enable you to do what you want straightforwardly.

My solution uses `Grid` to replicate the sacking of graphs you want.

As you can see, `Grid` has 3 `DateListPlot`s.

I use `ImagePadding` to align the left vertical axes of the plots. I have not found an automatic way to do this.  Maybe someone else has a suggestion.

I also use `ImagePadding` to overlap each successive plot over the one above it to the affect that it hides the bottom month labels for the 2 top plots.  Other ways exist to do this.  Let's see what other answers bring.

I've also added your TIME & 2020 in the bottom row of the `Grid`.

Comment: @ Jagra, thank you for your time. The Column function would not be appropriate to have one common x-axis and for time series of different lengths.

Answer (score 4):

Just to make sure that the `TimeSeries` objects have *unique* time signatures, I've written a few functions that create *randomly spaced* ranges of dates. These ranges start from `Today` plus or minus a random number of days and go back in time for a given number of *steps*.

Also, I provide a function that returns the *common* range for a number of different random date ranges (as described above).

Finally, in the code section, there's a function that composes a number of *value* lists and their corresponding *date* lists into `TimeSeries` objects.

```
Clear[randf, randomDate, aroundToday, randomDates]

(* Returns an integer between 3 and 7 *)
randf = (RandomInteger[{3, 7}, #] &) /* First;

(* Returns a date that is a random number of days before the input date *)
randomDate[date_, random_ : randf, unit_ : "Days"] := DatePlus[date, {-random[1], unit}];

(* Returns a random number of days before of after Today's date *)
aroundToday[random_ : randf, unit_ : "Days"] := DatePlus[Today, {RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] random[1], unit}];

(* Returns n randomly generated days starting from around Today and going back in random number of steps *)
randomDates[n_, random_ : randf, unit_ : "Days"] := With[{r = randomDate[#, random, unit] &},
  NestList[r, aroundToday[random, unit], n] // Reverse
 ]

(* Accepts lists of dates and returns their common range *)
dateRange[dates__] := Map[Through[{Min, Max}[#]] &, {dates}] // Transpose /* (
  MapThread[Construct, {{Min, Max}, #}] &)

(* Composes TimeSeries objects from a list of date lists and a list of value lists *)
(* A working assumption is that corresponding dates and values sublists are of the same Length ns[i]] *)
(* The returned TimeSeries have a random number of the original entries removed *)
makeTimeSeries[dates_, values_, ns_, random_ : randf] := MapThread[
  With[{t = #1, y = #2, is = RandomInteger[{1, #3}, randf[1]]},
    TimeSeries[#2, {#1}] & @@ Transpose[ReplacePart[Transpose[{t, y}], is -> Nothing // Thread]]
   ] &, {dates, values, ns}]
```

Making use of the code above, we can generate *truly* non-uniformly spaced dates for the values given in `{s1, s2, s3}`, which are the data with different lengths in the OP edit.

```
(* Obtained required data lengths *)
ns = Length /@ {s1, s2, s3};

(* Generate randomly spaced dates, starting from Today and extending back into the past *)
dates = Table[randomDates[n - 1], {n, ns}];

(* Finally, compose the corresponding TimeSeries objects *)
mytsdata = makeTimeSeries[dates, {s1, s2, s3}, ns]

(* Record the common range of the various date lists *)
rng = dateRange @@ ((#["Dates"] &) /@ mytsdata)
```

On my system, one evaluation of the code above produced eg.

[image]

[image]

Please, take note how all the time series have different ranges and different number of observations.

Now, in order to provide an answer to the OP, I have used the following function:

```
ClearAll[manyPlots]
Options[manyPlots] = {"Plot1" -> None, "Plot2" -> None, "Plot3" -> None};
manyPlots[ts_, opts : OptionsPattern[manyPlots]] := Module[{opts1, opts2, opts3, allOpts},
  allOpts = {opts1, opts2, opts3} = OptionValue[{"Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot3"}];
  MapThread[DateListPlot[#1, Apply[Sequence, #2]] &, {ts, allOpts}] // List /* Transpose /* GraphicsGrid
 ]
```

The `manyPlots` function, allows the user to pass different options to the various plots. Eg.

```
manyPlots[mytsdata, 
  "Plot1" -> {PlotLabel -> "a", PlotRange -> {rng, Automatic}}, 
    "Plot2" -> {PlotLabel -> "b", PlotRange -> {rng, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]]}, 
      "Plot3" -> {PlotLabel -> "c", PlotRange -> {rng, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[3]]}]
```

provides different labels to the plots and makes sure that they are all displayed over their common range. Also, it modifies the `PlotStyle` for the second and third plot.

[image]

I think that there are many other changes that can be accommodated using this approach.

Comment: @ joka, thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.