# Plot Figures in two columns

Tags: plotting

If I have stored 6 different figures in a command "decon" so that if I use `decon[[1]]` I plot the first figure and if I use `decon[[2]]` I plot the second figure and so on. The "decon" storage of the figures was obtained using the command `AppendTo`

**Question:**

Given this, how can I organize the figures in columns and put them with "a", "b", "c" and so on as the figure below for my an example of 4 particular figures (I would like all 6 of them in the same fashion):

[image]

If I use `Grid[{decon[[1 ;; 2]], decon[[3 ;; 4]]}]` as suggested by @Jagra, I get very compacted plots where it is difficult to see them:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: Using "GraphicsGrid", you may write e.g.: gr = Table[
   Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, Pi}, 
    Epilog -> Inset[StringForm["Number= ``", i], {.4, 1}]], {i, 4}];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[gr, 2]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
decon
```

[image]

```
Grid[{
  decon[[1 ;; 2]],
  decon[[3 ;; 4]]
  }]
```

[image]

[ResourceFunction, PlotGrid](http://ResourceFuntion%20--%20PlotGrid) can give you additional functionality.
(Nod to: @ Rohit's answer to: [Stacked time series plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233286/stacked-time-series-plot))

As example, which you can apply...

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Some Label"],
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]},
  {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Some Label"],
   Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]}
  }, Spacings -> {0, 30}
 ]
```

The `ResourceFunction` for `PlotGrid` makes some things easier related to having rows or columns of plots share axis information if you want something like that.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jagra! Thank you for your answer. When I use that I get very compacted plots (see above where I edited my question to include your answer). How can I solve this?

Comment: @John, simply set `ImageSize` of the `Plot`s to a size you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Jagra. It works !

Comment: Jagra, it might be useful for others to see how `PlotGrid` can automate the labeling too. Just a suggestion that if you could clarify how this might be possible, it would be useful to others?

Comment: @CATrevillian -- Interesting, but I can't say I've looked at doing it.  If you you have, feel free to add to the answer to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, display functions such as `Column`, `Grid` and `Row` automatically reduce the size of graphics. However, there's a simple option, [`ImageSizeMultipliers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html), that adjusts the size of the graphics. For example, `Grid` normally reduces the size of graphics:

```
SeedRandom[123]
{g1, g2, g3, g4} = 
  Table[ListPlot[RandomReal[10, {20, 2}], Joined -> True], {i, 4}];
Grid[{{g1, g2}, {g3, g4}}]
```

[image: without ImageSizeMultipliers]

Use the `ImageSizeMultipliers` style option to adjust the size of the graphics in the grid.

```
Grid[{{g1, g2}, {g3, g4}}, 
 BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1., 1.}]
```

[image: with ImageSizeMultipliers]