# Figures as a one column panel with same x axis but changing y axis

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, code-request

I have plots of 6 different figures in a command `decon` so that if I use `decon[[1]]` I plot the first figure and if I use `decon[[2]]` I plot the second figure and so on. The `decon` storage of the figures was obtained using the command `AppendTo`. The figures look like this after I manually plot each of them in two different rows:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I plot these figures as a one column panel where they share the same x axis (T in celsius) from 40 to 110 and the same y axis (Cp in J/gK) but the y-axis changes for each figure each time, similar to the manual sketch I did below:

[image]

Thank you in advanced for your help.

**EDIT AND UPDATE**

The result of the code done by @MassDefect is exactly what I want. The problem is that it doesn't work in my case because in his code `decon` is generating the ListPlot in a certain way. In my case I already have `decon` generated. When I put `decon` I get the following (I just changed a,b,c,d,e,f for something else but it is the same):

[image]

If I put `pg[Transpose[{decon}]]` I get my figures like this:

[image]

How can I modify the code so that when I do `pg[Transpose[{decon}]]` in my case it works?

Comment: How do you generate the figures in the first place? Currently, `decon` is a list that stores the full graphics objects, which includes things like the x axis labels. I'm thinking it might be easier to alter the original plotting commands than to strip these parts off of the already-generated graphics objects, but I want to know what you're working with first!

Comment: Also, just wondering: do you want the different figures to have the same vertical *scale*? That is, do you want a difference in 0.01 J/gK to correspond to the same vertical distance in figure a as figure e, even if the starting points are different?

Comment: @thorimur please see the update above that I believe answer your question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood, it seems like you just want a variation of the answer you received in [Plot Figures in two columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233887/plot-figures-in-two-columns).

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]}, {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]}, {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]}, {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> "Some Label"]}
  }, Spacings -> {0, 30}]
```

[image]

Essentially each grid row has a single element.

You can adjust `Spacings` to overlap `Axes` labels and show a single `Axis` on the bottom graph.

---

**In response to comments**...

```
decon =
 {{Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}]},
  {Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}]},
  {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}]},
  {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> "Some Label"]}}

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][decon, Spacings -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

You need to do some recasting of `decon` along the lines I have set out above.  You could do some of this programmatically on the fly, but that gets more complicated.

Comment: Jagra! Thank you very much for your code. I wanted the figure a little bit closer to what @MassDefect did above. The problem I am still having is that the code as done doesn't still work for my case for what I mention in the update of my question.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Jagra has the right idea using [PlotGrid](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid). You can do it manually using `Grid` or `GraphicsGrid` as well, but you end up having to tweak quite a few parameters. If you want to get them to share an x-axis, you can change Jagra's answer like this:

```
pg = ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"];
data = Table[{x, i PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]}, {i, 3}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];
decon = ListLinePlot[#, Axes -> False, Frame -> True] & /@ data;
pg[Transpose[{decon}]]
```

[image: PlotGrid]

If you have all of your graphs stored in `decon` and it's a 1-D list, you should be able to do the same thing:

```
pg[Transpose[{decon}]]
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like the sizing on your graphs is off. Maybe something like

```
pg[
  Transpose[{decon}],
  FrameLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}
  ImageSize -> 500
]
```

will help? It's hard to say for certain without being able to try your code exactly. My `decon` is also generated in a "certain way", so I think they should be fairly similar in theory. If you just call `decon` by itself with my code, you'll see that there are three distinct plots.

You may also need to change some options in your plots when you generate `decon` such as the label size and things like that. It's also possible to post-process `decon` using functions that go through the code contained in `decon` and replacing elements, but I'm not very good at that and there's no example code here to really test it on.

Comment: MassDefect, thank you very much. It looks exactly like I wanted it!. One question: How can I put the labels in the x and y axis in the center of each axis?

Comment: MassDefect, also can you look at the updated comments I did in my question?. Your code doesn't seem to be working in my case because my `decon` is already generated in a certain way. So I will just need to transpose it, but when I do it looks all very bad. Can you help me fix that?

Comment: @John I've made an edit based on your comments. Hopefully it helps a little bit.